# Code applied at top of page versus scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add conditional statements to my code but can't seem to get it to work. I want to apply `.nav-down-top` to #s-nav when the user is at the top of the screen , and `.nav-down` to #s-nav when not at top of page.

code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
  didScroll = false;
  }
}, 150);

function hasScrolled() {
 if($( window ).width() > 768) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {

        // Scroll Down
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');

    } else {



  // !!!! Code issue

        // Scroll Up (@ top of screen)
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down-top');

       } else {

        // Scroll Up (NOT @ top of screen)
        if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');

     }

  //


} else {
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}
lastScrollTop = st;
}
});
```

html

```
<nav id="s-nav" class="nav-down"> ...
```

Comment: Press F12 to open the developer tools, check the console. You have a few js errors.

Comment: ? the code works when I just include one of the scroll up if stateents but not 2. (I know I'm missing an else statement in between, but not sure if it's the right approach when trying to add 2)

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? I think at least part of the reason your code may not be working is you have 3 classes being added, but only one ever removed.

Comment: This code is for my navigation to 'drop down' from the top of the screen. It has .nav-down on at the start. When the user scrolls the navigation gets nav-up applied which animates it up off screen. I want that to happen, but I want to add a third class when the navigation is down at the top of the page ONLY. I want to add different margins etc when the user is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said, you weren't removing both unused classes and you had some issues with your code (missing closing angle brackets, orphaned else statement). The working function would look like this:

```
function hasScrolled() {
 if($( window ).width() > 768) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight ) {
        // Scroll Down
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('up').removeClass('top').addClass('down');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up (@ top of screen)
        if (st === 0) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('up').removeClass('down').addClass('top');
       } else {//if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#s-nav').removeClass('down').removeClass('top').addClass('up');
        }
    }
}
lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wm6kvm6u/

Comment: But I commend you, I am much closer to my goal. The issue I have is still the conflict when the user scrolls to the top. The moment they aren't at the top of the screen (scrolls down) it removes the nav-down-top and puts on nav-down so the navigation 'jumps' to the other class before animating up offscreen. I was hoping for a smooth transition, but I guess that requires a more complex function inside. The code you provided doesn't seem to animate correctly when I view it

Comment: as well,it doesn't always seem to apply the 'at the top of screen' function when the user scrolls up. Sometimes the nav-down-top doesn't get added. (or in your code example 'top') I'm not sure if i need the code to continuously monitor location or something

Comment: So you want the nav to disappear when the user scrolls down as opposed to up, like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wm6kvm6u/3/

Comment: For some reason nothing animates when i view your fiddles. I'll try to break it down better (Thanks for being so patient). I have a navigation bar across the top of the screen. When the user scrolls down, it transitions up out of view. When the user scrolls up it transitions back down into view. I just want to add another condition so when the user is at the top of the page, I want to the padding to increase in the navigation. So when the user scrolls down from the top of the page, it still transitions up out of view, and regular padding is applied.

Comment: The problem now seems to be when the user scrolls down from the top the other class is applied but sometimes doesn't transition out of screen (which is done when nav-up is applied) and sometimes when the user scrolls to the top of the page the regular nav-down is applied and not nav-down-top (which applies extra padding)

Comment: What browser are you using? `Transition: all` should work on any of the major browsers for the animation. I've added the padding and it looks to be working fine for me on Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/wm6kvm6u/4/ Here's a screencast of what I'm seeing: https://screencast.com/t/FrvuZVU69b

Comment: I must commend you on your professionalism. I am using firefox, And the red square doesn't move despite any scrolling. But based on your screen cast, I got it to work as your screencast does. And It shows near the end the issue that is happening. When you are at the top and scroll down, it doesn't always go up off-screen. Sometimes it just adds the regular padding and stays down. I want whenever the user scrolls down, no matter where they are, the navigation animates up. and whenever they are at the top the extra padding is added

Comment: In that case, just remove `&& st > navbarHeight` from the if statement checking if the user has scrolled down. https://jsfiddle.net/wm6kvm6u/5/

Comment: Oh ok, perfect! That seems to solve a bunch. But what if the page is reloaded/original visit. The user hasn't scrolled yet so the extra-padding class wouldn't be applied

Comment: I put it in the html, so it would be loaded when the user refreshes/first visits `<nav id="s-nav" class="top"></nav>`

Comment: oh ok, I missed that part. Thanks for all the help your quite the coder